# Truffle cannot find Ethereum client when running tests

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

By default this is the content of the file `truffle.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
    // to customize your Truffle configuration!
};
```

When I execute the command `truffle test` with the above configuration, it work well. However, if I change the configuration to this:

```
module.exports = {
    networks: {
        test: {
            network_id: '*',
            gas: 4712388,
            gasPrice: 10
        }
    }
};
```

When I execute the command `truffle test` I get the following error:

```
Could not connect to your Ethereum client. Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle.js)
```

I tried setting options `host` and `port` but still not working.

I'm using Truffle v4.1.14 on Mac.

Comment: which client are you using? ganache?

Comment: I'm using truffle develop. I just figured out that I had to start it manually. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For those who may stumble across this: I was stuck on this recently - everything seemed to be set correctly but Truffle refused to connect to Ganache (or vice versa). I kept getting the "Could not connect to your Ethereum client" message. On a lark, I tried changing the host address in truffle.js to reflect the computer's actual internal IP address (e.g. 10.10.1.188), and then telling Ganache to run on the Ethernet address instead of loopback. Much to my surprise, it worked immediately. I haven't yet figured out why (firewall rule? codebase issue?).

I realize this is not a best practice because your internal IP will change. But if you're in need of a temporary workaround, this may help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like when you change the configuration of the `test` network, Truffle Develop is not initialized automatically. So in order to make this work I had to run Truffle Develop manually:

```
truffle develop
```

And then in the `truffle.js` I put this config:

```
module.exports = {
    networks: {
        test: {
            network_id: '*',
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 9545,
            gas: 6712388,
            gasPrice: 100000000000
        }
    }
};
```

Doing that it started to work. I guess if you specify any of the parameters in the `test` network you have to manually take care of having the Ethereum client running.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Beware that default network is `development`-</s>

If you define `test` network, then you need to use parameter `--network test`

**Code from truffle** `truffle test`

```
// if "development" exists, default to using that for testing
if (!config.network && config.networks.development) {
  config.network = "development";
}

if (!config.network) {
  config.network = "test";
}
```

Comment: I think when you execute the command `truffle test` the default network is `test` instead of `development`

Comment: @dgaviola I put code from truffle above, default network is `development` but test command has fallback, it will work with `test` network if `development` is not defined. Sorry to mess you up.

Comment: I tried defining the `development` network too, but it doesn't work, I still need to manually run `truffle develop` to get it working.

Comment: @dgaviola before run tests you need to start test network, right? have you start `ganache`/`testrpc`?

Comment: @Alquila yes, I need to start a network with `truffle develop` before running the tests, and then in the `test` network I configured it to point to that network